# closed unit ball without a fixed point.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, fixed-point-theorems

What I've done so far:

Let $B=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n : \|x\| \leq 1\}$ be the closed unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$ equipped with the standard Euclidean metric. Let $f \colon B \to B$ be a function such that $\|f(x)-f(y)\|\leq\|x-y\|$ for all $x,y \in B$.

I have already shown $f$ has a fixed point.

Next the question asks me to:

Consider $B$ equal to the closed unit ball in $l^2$. $B = \left\{ (x_n) \in \mathbb R^\omega : \sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n^2 \leq 1 \right\}$ with the $l^2$-norm $\|x\|= \left( \sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n^2 \right)^{1/2}$, where $x=(x_n)$.

How do I prove this case does not have a fixed point?

Comment: What operators on $\ell^2$? do you know? There's a really standard example that is Lipschitz with norm $1$ and no fixed point.

Comment: Let the operator be some function that satisfies the contraction mapping theorem? I'm not 100% sure what you're asking. Also what is the example? Maybe I can work with that?

Comment: What operators do you know on $\ell^2$? As in, specific operators you've worked with.

Comment: This is the first time I have seen $l^2$

Comment: What if $f$ is the zero map? Then $f$ is 1-Lipschitz and has $0$ as a fixed point. Do you require something more, like surjectivity of $f$?

Comment: we have only shown that f is continuous and has a fixed point.